# The thingamajing problem in Head First JavaScript Programming

Tags: javascript

```js
function clunk(times) {
  let num = times
  while (num > 0) {
    display("clunk")
    num = num - 1
  }
}

function thingamajig(size) {
  let facky = 1
  clunkCounter = 0
  if (size == 0) {
    display("clank")

  } else if (size == 1) {
    display("thunk")
  } else {
    while (size > 1) {
      facky = facky * size
      size = size - 1
    }
    clunk(facky)
  }
}

function display(output) {
  console.log(output)
  clunkCounter = clunkCounter + 1
}
let clunkCounter = 0
thingamajig(5)

console.log(clunkCounter)
```

The above code is from "Head First JavaScript Programming".  I am confused, because by my logic, the answer should be that "clunk, clunk, clunk, clunk, clunk", should be logged to the console.  However, when I run the code through VS code, the answer is that "clunk" is logged to the console 120 times.  Could someone please explain why this is?.....thank you in advance.

Comment: You're calling `thingamajig(5)`, which calls `clunk(facky)` with `facky = 120`.

Comment: `facky` is the factorial of `size`, and `5! == 120`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  My brain is now able to grasp this.  Hopefully, I will be able to sleep.